# How do I put something on an FX thread?

Tags: java, exception, javafx, runtime-error

I'm new to JavaFX (trying to move from Swing), and am trying to make a very basic window first. However, I keep getting the following runtime exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = main
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:210)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:393)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:374)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:232)
    at bht.tools.util.upd.TestDialog.initGUI(TestDialog.java:39)
    at bht.tools.util.upd.TestDialog.<init>(TestDialog.java:24)
    at bht.tools.util.upd.TestDialog.main(TestDialog.java:52)
```

```java
package bht.tools.util.upd;

import java.awt.Window;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

/**
 * TestDialog is copyright Blue Husky Programming ©2014 GPLv3 <hr/>
 * 
 * @author Kyli of Blue Husky Programming
 * @version 1.0.0
 *      - 2014-09-30 (1.0.0) - Kyli created TestDialog
 * @since 2014-09-30
 */
public class TestDialog extends JDialog
{
    public TestDialog(Window owner)
    {
        super(owner);
        initGUI();
    }

    private JFXPanel holder;
    private Scene interior;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private GridPane root;
    private void initGUI()
    {
        {
            holder = new JFXPanel();
            setContentPane(holder);
            root = new GridPane();
            interior = holder.getScene();
            if (interior == null)
                holder.setScene(interior = new Scene(root));
            interior.setRoot(root);
        }
        {
            progressBar = new ProgressBar();
            progressBar.setProgress(-1);
            root.add(progressBar, 0, 1);
        }
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestDialog(null).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, looking at the `JFXPanel` source code, the constructor calls its `initFX()` method, which initializes the FX application thread. **Why, then, am I getting this error, and how do I fix it?**

Comment: So you're trying to embed an FX component into a Swing dialog? I don't think that's possible at all. AFAIK there are only mechanisms to do it the other way around.

Look at the new Application class for a basic start.

Comment: Sure it's possible; and [well documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE).

Comment: Just a comment: if you're trying to do something simple just to get your feet wet, combining Swing and FX is probably not a very easy place to start, as you have to work with two different UI threads. Why not start with a simple, all-FX application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JFXPanel` initializes the FX Application Thread, so it is now running; however your code is not being executed on that thread. In order to execute code on the FX Application Thread, you can call `Platform.runLater(...)` which is roughly analogous to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` in Swing and AWT applications.

This is taken more or less straight from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE), but for your example code you would do

```
package bht.tools.util.upd;

import java.awt.Window;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

/**
 * TestDialog is copyright Blue Husky Programming ©2014 GPLv3 <hr/>
 * 
 * @author Kyli of Blue Husky Programming
 * @version 1.0.0
 *      - 2014-09-30 (1.0.0) - Kyli created TestDialog
 * @since 2014-09-30
 */
public class TestDialog extends JDialog
{
    public TestDialog(Window owner)
    {
        super(owner);
        initGUI();
    }

    private JFXPanel holder;
    private Scene interior;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private GridPane root;
    private void initGUI()
    {
        holder = new JFXPanel();
        setContentPane(holder);
        Platform.runLater( () -> initJFXPanel(holder) );
        pack();
    }

    private void initJFXPanel(JFXPanel holder) {
        root = new GridPane();
        interior = holder.getScene();
        if (interior == null)
            holder.setScene(interior = new Scene(root));
        interior.setRoot(root);
        progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setProgress(-1);
        root.add(progressBar, 0, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TestDialog(null).setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note that you're breaking Swing's threading rules too, though I think (it's been a while now since I programmed using Swing) that Swing has been bullet-proofed to ensure code like that works. But your main method should really be

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TestDialog(null).setVisible(true));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All JavaFX Controls must be initialized or modified within the FX Application thread - this is by calling `Platform.runLater(() -> { //your JavaFX code });`

JFXPanel could be initialized inside the SwingUtility thread, but setting a JavaFX scene on the JFXPanel must be done within the FX Application thread. Example:

```
//still on Swing thread
JFXPanel panel = new JFXPanel();
//now setting the scene to be embedded on the JFXPanel
//this must be done inside the FX Application thread
Platform.runLater(() -> {
   Group group = new Group();
   group.getChildren.addAll(new Button("Cancel"), new Button("Save"), new Text("Status"));
   panel.setScene(new StackPane(group));
});
//back on the Swing thread
frame.add(panel);
```

Hope this helps.